# Physics.Raycast Grounddrag system not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting

I'm trying to implement a unity FPS Rigid body movement controller into my Unity 3d project. However I cannot seem to add drag to my player. I've been trying to do it with the following code:

```
private void Update()
    {
        //Ground check

        grounded = Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.down, playerHeight * 0.5f + 0.2f, whatIsGround);

        MyInput();

        //Handle drag
        if (grounded)
        {
            rb.drag = groundDrag;
        }
        else
        {
            rb.drag = 0;
        }
        
    }
```

Anyone have an idea as to what else I could try to add or fix with the script?

Comment: Does your raycast return true?

Comment: Sorry I'm new to Unity, how would I check this?

Comment: `Debug.Log($"Grounded? {grounded}");` after the `grounded = Physics...` line

Comment: Nothing comes up in the console when I put the code in my script

Comment: Is the script on the object?  Update runs every frame, and the Debug.Log is outside of any conditional statement, the script must not be attached to the object.

Answer (score 0):

If you defined the ground layer in the inspector, the problem seems to be here. Fix it with only replace `whatIsGround` to `whatIsGround.value`.

```
public LayerMask whatIsGround;
private void Update()
{
    grounded = Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.down, playerHeight * 0.5f + 0.2f, whatIsGround.value);
}
```

Comment: I did define it in the inspector but adding the .value at the end doesn't seem to work.

Comment: for define variable in body dosen't need to write .value, just in raycast condition.